# Change Image Url On Parent container hover

Tags: html, css

I need to change image once user hovers over any text (say Hello) on the list item.

[image]

```
<li id="li1"> <img id="img1" width="50" height="50"/>Hello</li>

#li1{
    list-style:none
}
#li1:hover{

}

#img1
{
    content: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png');
}
#img1:hover{
    content: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png');
}
```

But I could achieve to change image only when use hovers over the image.

Is it possible to do this using CSS only?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/e5aSv/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments by [Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d), the `content` property should not be relied on in this way, instead the visibility of the images can be triggered on hover, which you simply need to apply to the parent `li`:

Change your HTML to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/e5aSv/5/)

```
<li>
    <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png' />
    <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png' />Hello</li>
```

And then use the following CSS:

```
li {
    list-style:none
}
img {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
li img:last-of-type {
    display:none;
}
li:hover img:first-of-type {
    display:none;
}
li:hover img:last-of-type {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks `SO` does not allow me to accept your answer within 9 mins. I wish I could.

Comment: correct me If i am wrong.. but i can't see image on Firefox 29.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `content` property should **not** be used in that way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: @Paulie_D - correct, I was applying to the OPs code, but you're right, it should be more educational- updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for this.

```
#li1:hover #img1 {
    content: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png');
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/79EA9/1/)

Comment: when using `img` element `src` attribute is required. and Firefox doesn't support the `content` property as like chrome support, so it won't work in Firefox.

Comment: Changed the code for browser compatibility. http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/79EA9/2/.

Answer (score 0):

ok there is a fix for this little bug where on hover the element becomes smaller and the text moves left<->right.

just replace ur hrml with this

```
<li><!--
--><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png' /><!--
--><img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png' />Hello</li><!--
-->
```

when u are using inline elements like li span a etc. the browser put some white-space betweent them. The shown above fixs that :)

Answer (score 0):

[FiddleLink](http://jsfiddle.net/ES5ty/)

Use following code

```
#li1:hover #img1{
content: url('images.jpg');
}
```

Thanks